# MySQL: Error Querying Database *AFTER* Copy & Pasted Database into MySQL\Data Folder

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I have had apache, php, and mysql server 5.5 installed locally and happily running for a while now, able to query the databases and everything.  Today, I **copy and pasted** sample databases into the Mysql\Data folder from a SQL Query course book: SQL Queries for Mere Mortals, by John Viescas.

**THE PROBLEM**

When I try to query the databases I get an error telling me the **database table(s)** do not exist, when they actually do exist.

Error Code: 1146. Table 'bowlingleagueexample.bowler_scores' doesn't exist

**What I have Tried**

Based on my research, it probably has something to do with permissions?
I'm not a database guy, but am trying to learn.  I have viewed the databases with MySQL Workbench, and PHPMyAdmin.  Workbench shows me the tables, but errors out on the query execution.  PhpMyAdmin won't even show me the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You usually can't hot-swap database tables. You need to use the proper `mysqldump` and restore procedure. You can seriously trash your MySQL installation if you make a habit of doing this, especially with InnoDB tables.

PhpMyAdmin has a load and save snapshot feature that helps with this sort of thing. Give it a valid `.sql` file and you should be fine.

Comment: Hi Tadman - how is it possible to create a dump from a database that does not appear on my current server?  The books's database popped out of an executable that installed it's own directory on my C-drive.  So I have Apache installed, then MySQL with it's data elsewhere, and then the Mere Mortals Executable that installed their databases on C:\AddisonWesley\SQLQFMM2\MySQL\Data

Comment: There are different ways of loading in a dump depending on your tool. Some allow you to upload a `.sql` file via a form and have it rolled in. If you can get a `.sql` file of some sort, you're on the right track. It is very unusual to hot-swap the actual raw database files, especially since these are highly MySQL version specific.

Comment: Your input prompted me to try another method of getting the databases loaded. The databases came with instructions (not so great instructions which took me a while to figure out) for a 3 step process for using their provided SQL 3 SQL files per sample database to 1) create the database structure, 2) load the sample database data, and 3) load the sample views/queries.  I tried this a number of times with Workbench with no success!  Then, for some reason I decided to try it with PhpMyAdmin and the 3 step process worked.  So I'm good to go now.

Thanks for your troubleshooting help.